# Change color on checkmark in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uicolor

Could someone be so kind to show me how to change the color on the checkmark in UITableView?

I have searched but don't seem to get it to work.

Cheers

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Apple doesn't provide a public way to change the color of the checkmark so you'll have to do it with an image.

This is very simple, just set the accesoryView property of the cell to a UIImageView containing a checkmark of the correct color.

It'll look like this:

```
UIImageView *checkmark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"coloredCheckmark.png"]];
cell.accessoryView = checkmark;
[checkmark release];
```

Enjoy!

Comment: But accessory view is on the right, not on the left side, am I right?

Comment: Nope, right side: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Just out of interest, what size did you create the image at (in points)?

Comment: It can really be any size you like, but I believe the normal checkmark is around 28x28 pnts.

Comment: From iOS 7 you can change check mark color by setting UIWindow's Tint Color.

Comment: You can also change the checkmark color by setting the tintColor property of the table view cell now. Hi Zimmer :)

Answer (score 211):

Since the iOS SDK has changed since the accepted answer, I thought I'd just update with a new answer.

You can in fact change the color of the checkmark in a `UITableViewCell` by adjusting the `tintColor` property of the `UITableViewCell.`

You can also set an appearance proxy for all UITableViewCells so that ALL instances have a specific tint color unless otherwise specified

```
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Swift:
In Swift change the tintcolor to the color you want to change the color of any Accessory Type

```
cell.tintColor = .black
```

Comment: Yes Anastasia, the property tintColor is available for UIView in iOS 7.0 and later.

Comment: Wonder why they don't set the accessory view when we set the accessory type so we can customize it instead of going for hacks like setting the tint color for the entire cell or table just so the checkmark color changes.

Comment: This does not seem to work any more in iOS 9.3, unless I am missing something. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: It works in 10.1, you can also set it in Interface Builder.

Comment: Note that, if you've used the UIAppearance protocol to set UIControl's `tintColor`, the checkmark accessory type will inherit that color instead of UITableViewCell's `tintColor`.  You may need to do something like this to override it: `UIControl.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [CustomTableViewCell.self]).tintColor = .white`

Answer (score 35):

If you are looking for a Swift version:

#### Directly on the cell

For example in `tableView(_:,cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`

```
cell.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

#### Using the appearance protocol

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Answer (score 29):

The following worked for me in iOS 7.

```
[self.tableView setTintColor:[UIColor someColor]];
```

Comment: there is no such color as [UIColor someColor].  I think you meant [UIColor bestColor] ?

Answer (score 15):

This image shows how to do this in storyboards.The Tint color is the checkmark color.

[image]

Comment: It worked for me. If not, you can try the programmatic way as described in the accepted answer.

Comment: This worked perfectly and should be the correct answer to edit checkmark color while selecting a cell

Answer (score 14):

I found that igraczech's answer is mostly correct, but with iOS 6 or later, you can just set the tint color of the entire tableview and default items will inherit down.

```
[self.tableView setTintColor:[UIColor someColor]];
```

This worked for me and allowed me to color in the checkmark.

Comment: Pretty sure this works in iOS 6. You are setting the tint of the tableview and not some other object?

Comment: Definitely it don't work in iOS 6. Be careful when you confirm something

Answer (score 8):

Starting iOS 7 you could set the tint color of your view controller's view so that this tint colow will be propageted to all it's child views. So to set your UITableViewCell's checkmark as purple color (for example), in your viewWillAppear method you need to:

```
[self.view setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

Answer (score 3):

The UIAccessoryTypeCheckmark (right side) inherits background color of its tableview.

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
HNCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HNCustomTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.99 green:0.74 blue:0.10 alpha:1.0];
return cell;
}
```

It work for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
 UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.tintColor=UIColor.whiteColor;
return cell;
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more commentary as to what this block of code does?

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: @Deanna When a UITableViewCell is selected, the OS goes through the view hierarchy and changes the backgroundColor of tableView to selected colour

Comment: @Raviteja_DevObal can you update the answer? It was flagged as low quality as it was just a snippet of code with no explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
#import "UIImage+Color.h"

UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_check_black_24dp.png"] changeColor:CLR_BUY];
UIImageView *checkmark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
cell.accessoryView = checkmark;
```

Answer (score 2):

I always used this easy way:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = ...;
cell.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use your own image, you can simply change it in your view did load with the following code.

```
[self.tableView setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:250/255.0 green:223/255.0 blue:6/255.0 alpha:1]]
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.1, iOS 9+**

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            UIImageView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableViewCell.self]).tintColor = UIColor.themeTint //add your color here 
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are all great. But if you want to do it globally, just do

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().tintColor = .green
```

Nice little trick :)