# UITableViewCellAccessoryType Change checkmark colour

Tags: uitableview, swift

I am trying to figure out how to programmatically(not in storyboard) set the colour for UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark.

I feel kinda stupid asking how to do something as simple as this, but I could not find the answer in the apple docs. Any help would be great. Thanks.

I set the accessory type like this:(works fine)

```
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
```

EDIT : If you want to change the image used for checkmark, this worked for me. But POB's answer is what I ended up using to simply change the colour.

```
    let checkImage = UIImage(named: "checkmark.png")
    let checkmark = UIImageView(image: checkImage)

    cell.accessoryView = checkmark
```

Comment: See [the second answer to this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641228/change-color-on-checkmark-in-uitableview) (Objective C).

Comment: @POB I see...Thanks for the link. Will update post with working code :)

Comment: cell.accessoryView = custom checkmark Image -> still works with swift 2.2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    //Change cell's tint color
    cell.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

    //Set UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark here if necessary
    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark

    /* ... */

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is code for Swift 3.0

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.tintColor = UIColor.red
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it globally (for all table view cells) like this:

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().tintColor = .green
```

Nice little trick :)