# How to change UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark's color?

Tags: swift, uitableview, checkmark

Here's my code:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
```

But when I run the app, I can't see the checkmark.

Then I set background color to black, and I can see a white checkmark.

How to change checkmark's color to other colors like blue?

Comment: Hi there - how do you change the background color?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SWIFT - UITableViewCellAccessoryType Change checkmark colour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045738/swift-uitableviewcellaccessorytype-change-checkmark-colour)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes you can do it.

Just set the `tintColor` of cell.

```
cell.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
```

**Swift 3**

```
let aCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
aCell.tintColor = UIColor.red
aCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
return aCell
```

[image: OUTPUT]

**You can also do it from Attributes Inspector**

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: Sorry @Ashish Kakkad, your solution works very well with checkmark accessory, but Apple has a issue with disclosure accessory. No solution works with disclosures. (A changed my vote for you) =]

Comment: @HenriqueGüttlerMorbin It's okay. If I found anything about disclosures then I post here. :)

Answer (score 11):

Just set the tint color of UITableViewCell from **Attribute Inspector** or by coding like below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "SimpleTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    // just add below lines
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    cell.tintColor = UIColor.red


    return cell
}
```

@HenriqueGüttlerMorbin check this hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the colour in your cell class (the one subclassing the UITableViewCell class). Set the tintColor property in your awakeFromNib method if you want the same colour to be applied for all the rows of your table view. Like so:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    accessoryType = .checkmark
    tintColor = .red
}
```

Of course, if you set the colour in the cellForRowAt method of your view controller, you can use the indexPath parameter in your favour to set different colours according to the row displayed.