# UITableView invisible checkmark

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController where a prototype cell named `langCell` is defined.
(see figure A)

Its accessory type is set to `Checkmark` which is supposed to be a blue checkmark appearing on the right side of the cell. (see figure B)

After having set this option, I did not see any "blue" checkmark appearing in the storyboard. I tried to change the background colour of the prototype cell to grey and the checkmark appeared back. (see figure C)

Why the default colour for checkmark is white? It is not visible.
How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Check tint colour of cell / parent views.

Comment: set the tint color of tableview as you want to display.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change color on checkmark in UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641228/change-color-on-checkmark-in-uitableview)

Answer (score -1):

You can show checkmark by two ways -

1) Set the cell's tintColor property as-

```
[cell setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

2) Set the accesoryView property of the cell to a UIImageView containing a checkmark of the correct color as-

```
UIImageView *checkMark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"coloredCheckmark.png"]];
cell.accessoryView = checkMark;
[checkMark release];
```

Comment: 2) is not good at all. And it is just copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641228/change-color-on-checkmark-in-uitableview without a quootation. And it uses ARC, which you are not supposed to be doing any more!