# How to fill color in checkbox and set the height and widht of checkbox in xamarin forms?

Tags: android, checkbox, xamarin.forms

I am wokring in xamarin forms. I am using checkbox. I want to fill the color in checkbox and need to change the size of it. But when I am trying to set its HeightRequest and WidthRequest its not working. And also if I am trying to set its background color its also showing outside of it.

Please tell me how I can fill color in checkbox and can change the height and width?

Regards,
Anand Dubey

Comment: You will need to create a Custom Renderer of the View you are using in order to do what you need.

Comment: I tried with custom renderer also but it is also not working. Do you have any idea which property I should use in custom renderer to fill the color in checkbox and which property I should use to change the height and width of checkbox?

Comment: For android it may be: buttonTint, here are some links related to Android and iOS checkboxes:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854047/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-checkbox
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641228/change-color-on-checkmark-in-uitableview